# How to run c++ program in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know how to set the environment to debug and run the c++ code in vscode please help me to resolve this issue....

I have downloaded mingw(gcc compiler) to set environment but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Try a directory name without + signs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

From vscode terminal of your cpp file directory--

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
./test
```

Assuming the cpp file name is test.cpp.If you don't have admin permission use sudo before g++